# RODBC: Create access tables with lookup tables

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

I have been assigned to create databases for survey questionnaire.

I use R to store survey information in a semi-complex data structure with formats, questions, response levels, etc. This makes it easy to process and clean the data as well as generating reports. However, I now need to go one step further and create a blank database so that data entry forms can be generated.

To do this, I need to be able to generate blank databases from R, based on specifications, that have "constraints" on the types of data that can be entered. In R, this is similar to the factor datatype, in Access it is the lookup table.

If I create a blank dataframe in R and use the `sqlSave` command, however, the factor information does *not* carry over to the access database.

For instance:

```
library(RODBC)
con <- odbcConnectAccess2007('blankdb.accdb')
survey <- data.frame('id'=integer(0), 'age'=integer(0), sex=factor(levels=c('Male', 'Female')))
sqlSave(con, survey)
survey.copy <- sqlFetch(con, survey)

levels(survey$sex)
levels(survey.copy$sex)
```

Surveys have coded levels for responses. I would like to be able to create tables for data entry that have coded levels for responses, e.g. "What level of education have you achieved?" 0) No certificate 1) High school graduate / GED 2) College graduate 3) Postgraduate degree.

Comment: Is your information stored in Access, or in R?  If you are using R, I would think the `factor` data type would be helpful since it has both an integer value you could map to (1 + response code) and then a level you can use to interpret the code.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 good question. I tried to edit the question. If the datatype is factor in R, when I use `sqlSave`, the table loses all the information in Access.

Comment: I am not sure that there is a direct mapping between these datatypes via `RODBC`, though my knowledge of that package (and Access) is limited.  Have you thought about just coercing `sex=as.character(sex)` or `data.frame(...stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` and then re-casting it in Access?  Or is that what you're trying to avoid doing?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 that would be wrong since fudgy-fingered data enters might enter "Femael" or something like that. Isn't there a way to use SQL code to create a table with some relation, constraints, or keyed values... I'm just not too familiar with that. I keep getting errors when trying to use something like a constraint clause.